# let x and Y be independent standard normal random variables . then what is the distribution of U= [(x+y)/(x-y)]^2

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable

let x and Y be independent standard normal random variables . then the distribution of U= [(x+y)/(x-y)]^2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $Y_1=X+Y$, 
   $Y_2=X-Y$

The distribution of sum of two independent standard normal is  $Y_1\sim N(0,2)$, for $X-Y$ the distribution is still $Y_2\sim N(0,2)$.

You can use mgf,convolution or variable transformation to prove above relationship.

I will not show the proof above.

Next,  you are asking the distribution of $(\frac{Y_1}{Y_2})^2$

Let $$U=(\frac{Y_1}{Y_2})^2=\frac{[\sqrt{2}*N_{y_1}(0,1)]^2}{[\sqrt{2}N_{y_2}(0,1)]^2}=\frac{\chi_{y_1}^2(1)}{\chi_{y_2}^2(1)}$$

The ratio of independent chi-squares, each divided by its degrees of freedom, has a [F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution)

So for your case $U$ has a $F(d_1=1,d_2=1)$ distribuiton

Comment: This is pretty clearly a [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) (routine textbook) question, and should be treated as such (even though it doesn't carry the tag yet). You've just completely solved it. It might have been better to outline parts of it, giving hints.

Comment: This outline skips over the fact that the ratio of two *independent* chi-squares (divided by their degrees of freedom) is F-distributed, but the ratio was of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ ... why should they be independent? We know the original $X$ and $Y$ were independent. (It isn't especially difficult to show they are independent, but this necessity should at least be acknowledged.)